# change values of a csv file into an integer value of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, jupyter-notebook

I have a .csv list of values (C3,H5,HK,HA,SK) (column names: card1, card2, card3, card4, card5) and want to change for example C3 into an integer value with a dictionary.
Let's say the dictionary is d = {'C2': 0, 'C3': 1, 'C4': 2, 'C5': 3, 'C6': 4, 'C7': 5, 'C8': 6, 'C9': 7, 'CT': 8, 'CJ': 9, 'CQ': 10, 'CK': 11, 'CA': 12, 'D2': 13, 'D3': 14, 'D4': 15, 'D5': 16, 'D6': 17, 'D7': 18, 'D8': 19, 'D9': 20, 'DT': 21, 'DJ': 22, 'DQ': 23, 'DK': 24, 'DA': 25, 'H2': 26, 'H3': 27, 'H4': 28, 'H5': 29, 'H6': 30, 'H7': 31, 'H8': 32, 'H9': 33, 'HT': 34, 'HJ': 35, 'HQ': 36, 'HK': 37, 'HA': 38, 'S2': 39, 'S3': 40, 'S4': 41, 'S5': 42, 'S6': 43, 'S7': 44, 'S8': 45, 'S9': 46, 'ST': 47, 'SJ': 48, 'SQ': 49, 'SK': 50, 'SA': 51}
this is the code I have to change the column of 'card1':

```
testdata = read_csv()
def convert_card_to_int(c):
    if c == '' or c == ' ':
        print ('card slot is empty or a blank')
        return 0
    if c in d:
        return d.get(c)
    else:
        print ('card is not part of cardDict')
        return 0

for index, rec in testdata.iterrows():
    testdata['card1'][index] = convert_card_to_int(testdata['card1'][index])

testdata['card1'] = testdata['card1'].astype(int)
```

I am new in python and have not worked with dictionaries before. So I was searching some forums but did not get anything I needed, maybe I was even typing the wrong questions.
Well the problem is that I want to check if the value of the list is a value of the dictionary and if it is then it should replace it with the integer value. 
The second if statement is the part where the problem occurs. Or it is in the for loop beneath. The error message tells me that it is a [TypeError: unhashable type 'dict']

testinput (file.csv):

```
card1,card2,card3,card4,card5
C3,H5,HK,HA,SK
C9,HJ,ST,SQ,SA
S6,S7,S8,S9,ST
```

testoutput:

```
testdata.head()
idx card1 card2 card3 card4 card5
0   1     H5    HK    HA    SK
1   7     HJ    ST    SQ    SA
2   43    S7    S8    S9    ST
```

Comment: `.itervalues` will return all the integers in the dict.  That's not what you want, you want to see if the *key string* exists in the dict.

Comment: can you gives a input and output example to be more clear about what are you asking

Comment: @MarkRansom: so if I change it to : 'if c in d:' it would be correct?

Comment: @ShubhamShaswat: I edited the text and added a test in/output

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Comment: well after changing it, it still throws an error message called TypeError even if casting the return value to an int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for this

`df=pd.read_csv(filepath)`

d is your dictionary

`d={{'C2': 0, 'C3': 1, 'C4': 2, 'C5': 3, 'C6': 4, 'C7': 5, 'C8': 6....}`

if you want to do for a specific columns Ex: `card1` you can do like this

```
df['card1'] = df['card1'].apply(lambda x:str(d[x]))
```

Comment: I found a way it worked for my preferences, I will post it when in reach of the code and find time for it, but I will try out your method as well